# UICollectionView with paging some content is off screen Objective-c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I've tried some solutions found on stackoverflow such as

```
self.collectionView.clipsToBounds = NO;    
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
```

And nothing is working. 
My collection view has a cell in it and should display one cell at a time. I'm using paging and evertyhing is working fine except that when you go to the second page it cuts a little of the cell off by the screen. And every page you go after that cuts more of the cell of till you get to the last page where half the cell is cut off. I'm doing this on iphone.

Comment: there is something wrong in your frame that you can solve by putting different values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was min spacing for lines was on 10 so I set it to 0. I think thats a bug in xcode 5 because my collection view is scrolling horizontal not vertical so one would think it would be my min spacing for cells would be wrong

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is, your cell is not centered, so as you swipe between them, and the UICollectionView dynamically figures out the spacing of each cell, it gradually becomes more and more off centre, getting the effect you explain.

Ensure that your `UICollectionViewCell` + `UICollectionViewLayout` insets equal the width of the contentView of your `UICollectionView`.

e.g.

On a 320.0f,100.0f UICollectionView. Your cell could be 300.0f,90.0f. And your UICollectionViewLayout (if using a flowLayout), could have the edge insets set to 5.0f,10.0f,5.0f,10.0f.

E.g.

```
[(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)collectionView.collectionViewLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(320.0f, 100.0f)];

[(UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)collectionView.collectionViewLayout setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5.0f, 10.0f, 5.0f, 10.0f)];
```

Comment: It would be nice if UICollectionView was smart enough to adjust its paging size to be the cell size plus the insets.

Answer (score -1):

Please make each item in a section, NOT all items in one section.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return [self.items count];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}
```

That's done.